# Angular js ng-show not working properly

Tags: json, angularjs, ng-show

I have a function that executes when my html form is submitted, if there are errors while processing the form on the server the errors are returned as a json. I want to display these errors to the user, but for some reason the ng-show on my error div container never displays.

Html code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="registerForm" ng-controller="RegisterController as register" ng-submit="registerForm.$valid && register()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="email">Email: </label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ng-model="d.email" class="form-control" ng-required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ng-model="d.password" class="form-control" ng-required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="confPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-9">
                <input type="password" id="password_confirmation" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="d.password_confirmation" nx-equal-ex="d.password" class="form-control" ng-required/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <span class="help-block errorMessages" ng-show="d.errors.length">
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                <ul class="list">
                    <li ng-repeat="error in d.errors"><% error %></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </span>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <br/>
                <hr>
                <button class="big-red-button" type="submit">Register <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Register.js Controller:

```
(function() {

    angular.module('vendor').controller('RegisterController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {

        $scope.d = {};
        $scope.d.errors = {};

        $scope.register = function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/auth/register",
                headers : {
                    'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
                },
                data: {
                    email: $scope.d.email,
                    password: $scope.d.password,
                    password_confirmation: $scope.d.password_confirmation
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(result[0]);
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                    var responseJSON = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    $scope.d.errors = responseJSON;
                    //alert($scope.d.errors.name);

                }
            });
        };

    }]);

}) ();
```

Nothing happens when the errors are returned to the page, ng-show does not display the code.

Comment: the length always exist, so, you need to specify something like `ng-show="d.errors.length > 0"` if nothing is saved in the error before.

Comment: tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: then, use `ng-show="d.errors !== undefined"`

Comment: Wow that actually worked, wasn't expecting it to :D

Answer (score 0):

Use data binding to show the errors:

```
<ul class="list">
 <li ng-repeat="error in d.errors"><% error %>{{error}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand, this looks like what i already have in my code.

Comment: How do you do the data binding in the view ? By this only <% error %> ?
Aren't you suppose to use {{error}}

Comment: I changed it to <% %> because it conflicted with my laravel blade tempate

Comment: Ah I see what you did .OK let me check then

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but $.ajax is a jQuery? If so,

Anything outside angular universe needs to trigger digest cycle manually.

So you got two options.

after $scope.d.errors = responseJSON add

```
$scope.$apply();
```

Or use [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
 $http.post({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/auth/register",
   headers : {
     'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
   },
   data: {
     email: $scope.d.email,
     password: $scope.d.password,
     password_confirmation: $scope.d.password_confirmation
   }
 }).success(
   function(data) {
     alert(data[0]);
   }
 ).error(function(err, status, headers, conf) {
     $scope.d.errors = data;
     //alert($scope.d.errors.name);
 });
```

Comment: $scope.$apply() didn't work and had a whole different issue when using $http that's why i switched to $ajax

Comment: $scope.$apply() should update update your dom as expect. Did you tried this $http snippet? Did not test it but it should work

Comment: It works just fine when i use $http.post, my issue with it was, the response always ended up being an html page instead of json, simply because laravel validation checks the page request if it's an ajax request it returns a json object if not thenit does a redirect.